# htaccess mod_rewrite doesn't recognize '-'

Tags: .htaccess

I have a clean url rewrite function in my .htaccess, it works fine unless if there's a "-" in the link for example my-pages.php. I need to know how to add that as a condition to:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a dash at the begin or the end of your character class:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ $1.php
```

If a dash is added at the begin or the end of a character class, it isn't treated as a special character.

Comment: +1 If OP decides to include `_` too, he can use `[\w-]` as well.

Comment: @Ravi: +1 Nice addition!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a non-greedy `.*` to catch anything up to a possible slash:

```
RewriteRule  ^(.*?)\/?$ $1.php
```